# Create podspec to ship static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries, cocoapods, .a

I'm trying to ship a static library via cocoapods. I was given the library without any build directions right now its a drop in to my iOS app. I don't need to build the library for each application using it, rather just download the lib files and include the headers. Is there a way to do this with a podspec file?

Here's what I have thus far:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "RTMPLib Library"
  s.version      = "1.0.0"
  s.summary      = "RTMPLib Library"
  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/jumper/RTMPLib.git"
  s.license      = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author       = { "jon morehouse" => "jon@jumperapp.com" }
  s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/jumper/RTMPLib.git", :tag => "#{s.version}" }
  s.platform     = :ios, '7.0'

  # arc components
  s.requires_arc = false
  s.preserve_paths = 'inc/rtmplib/*.h'
  s.vendored_libraries = 'lib/rtmplib.a'
  s.libraries = 'rtmplib'
  s.xcconfig = { 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '${PODS_ROOT}/#{s.name}/inc/rtmplib/**'}
  s.preserve_paths = 'L.framework'
end
```

The actual code structure can be found here: [Git Repo](http://github.com/jumper/RTMPLib)

Comment: This seems like a similar problem to:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102703/cocoapod-podspec-and-framework

Comment: Your Git Repo link is broken

Answer (score 4):

Sure it's possible, and it's easy. Your podspec looks correct.

I think you should create a *.framework and put your library and header files inside, so it's easier to manage. Here's an example podspec for a framework:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = "LibName"
  s.version          = "0.2.0"
  s.summary          = "MySummary"

  s.homepage         = "http://myWebpPage.com/"

  s.license          = 'MIT'
  s.author           = { "Author" => "http://author.com/" }
  s.source           = { :git => "https://github.com/<GITHUB_USERNAME>/Project.git", :tag => s.version.to_s }

  s.platform     = :ios, '7.0'
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'StaticLibraryFolder/StaticLibrary.framework'
  s.frameworks = 'CoreData' , 'SystemConfiguration', 'CoreLocation'
  s.weak_framework = 'UIKit'

end
```

If you don't want to do it with a *.framework file, but with *.a and *.h files instead, [here's](https://github.com/Appboy/appboy-ios-sdk/blob/master/Appboy-iOS-SDK.podspec) an example.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about, it doesn't make sense to me at all. Please read up on "*.framework" extension in the Apple system - it's basically a folder, how can that make anything harder to manage?

An advice for the future: when you think someone's wrong, don't condescend and try to insult them by laughing. Maybe try a civil discussion? Especially that it might turn out that you're the one in the wrong.

Have a nice day and many, many laughs here on Stackoverflow!

Comment: Is using `s.ios.vendored_frameworks` helps in shipping a static lib via cocopods. Is it possible that this will be treated as a dynamic library?

Comment: I create framework contain static lib and header, then pod lib lint spec , it show framework not found error?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need do like that [demo](https://github.com/dorentus/libBPush/blob/master/libBPush.podspec)

```
 Pod::Spec.new do |s|
 s.name         = "RTMPLib Library"
 s.version      = "1.0.0"
 s.summary      = "RTMPLib Library"
 s.homepage     = "https://github.com/jumper/RTMPLib.git"
 s.license      = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
 s.author       = { "jon morehouse" => "jon@jumperapp.com" }
 s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/jumper/RTMPLib.git", :tag => "#{s.version}" }
 s.platform     = :ios, '7.0'

 # arc components
 s.requires_arc = false
# you static library`s .h file
 s.source_files = 'lib/*.h'
 s.vendored_libraries = 'lib/rtmplib.a'

end
```

Comment: The `s.vendored_libraries` line is what I was missing.